# Consultation on rapid big data entry to sql-server through C# - bulk

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

i have C# WinForm program that i need to insert fast big data to sql-server.

The sql-server is in cloude server, and the file that i load in local computer.

the file is Text (Tab delimited) in

**d:\TEST\TEST.txt** and has *Full permissions*

```
BAR    DES     MAK
111    aaa     222
333    bbb     333
.
.
```

the sql-server table is **CatTbl**:

```
BAR nvarchar(250)
DES nvarchar(250)
MAK nvarchar(250)
```

i try to insert like this:

```
SQL = @"BULK INSERT CatTbl FROM 'd:\TEST\TEST.txt' WITH (CODEPAGE=1255,FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t')";
Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, Conn);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.Dispose();
```

when i work on local sql-server its works excellent.

but in cloude sql-server i got error:

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "d:\TEST\TEST.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 21(The device is not ready.).
```

- Please note that the sql-server connection is successful

I searched the web and found no answer that solved the problem. I would appreciate some help

Comment: Does `d:\TEST\TEST.txt` exist on your cloud SQL Server? Are you using Azure SQL? Something else?

Comment: If the file is accessible on the client, use SqlBulkCopy in you app instead of T-SQL `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: d:\TEST\TEST.txt not exist on my cloud. i dont use Azure SQL i use the regular SQL-server.  the file TEST.txt in on the client

Comment: [data_file must specify a valid path from the server on which SQL Server is running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

So you need to work in the mindset of "where am I right now?". When your're on your computer, D:\ is the drive in your physical box. If you tell the server "I'm loading a bulk file, and its in D:\file.txt", it's not going to look at -your- computer's D:\, its going to look at its -own- D:\, and the file isn't there.

What you need to do is upload the file somewhere first, that the server an access, and then tell the server what path to the file is, relative to him.